# Pass data between JavaScript and C# Controller : Asp.Net MVC 4 Razor

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to pass data between my view and my controller. I'm doing something wrong because it doesn't work.

JavaScript Front-end Code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetOid","SearchPerson")',
    data:  {oid : 1},
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        // return values 
        console.log("Success!" + data.oid); 
    },
    error: function () { console.log('error!!'); }
});
```

C# Controller Code:

```
    int CustomerId=0;

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetOid(int Oid)
    {

        // some code here to assign the value to a global var.
        CustomerId = Oid;

        ViewBag.id = Oid;


        return Json(new { oid = CustomerId });
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this change to your ajax data property. It needs to be passed as string.

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "Oid": 1 }),
```

Also your controller parameters and data parameters are need to be same. The are case sensitive.

```
public ActionResult GetOid(int Oid)
```

Last as mentioned return it in json format.

```
return Json(new { oid = CustomerId });
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't know anything about variables you set on the server. You need to return json to client like so:

```
 return Json(new { oid = CustomerId });
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
public JsonResult GetOid(int Oid)
```

to set the response headers properly

Answer (score 0):

This baffled many newbies,

```
console.log("Success!" + **data.Data.oid**);
```

You should learn fire debugger on browser side and look at what concerns you on watch window.

Comment: i use firebug, but i test in chrome and ie. 
and yes, i'm newbie.